# snowflake create database with variable

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a database using variable in snowflake

```
set var='mytestdb';
create database  IF NOT EXISTS $var;
```

Is this possible? The above query is giving me error.

Comment: Hi @Marcel, the code is as above. just set a variable and use the variable name while creating the database.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use identifier:

```
set my_var = 'test_database';
select $my_var;
create database IF NOT EXISTS identifier($my_var);
```

Result:

```
1
Statement executed successfully.
1
test_database
1
TEST_DATABASE already exists, statement succeeded.
```

For more information:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html

Variables can also contain identifier names, such as table names. To use a variable as an identifier, you must wrap it inside IDENTIFIER(), e.g. IDENTIFIER($MY_VARIABLE). Some examples are below: